# Insert XmlFile (or other) from camel route to mongoDB

Tags: json, spring, mongodb, apache-camel

I've been trying to insert a XML file into mongoDB with camel and I can't manage to make it work.

I've followed this tutorial for the first steps:
http://www.pretechsol.com/2014/09/apache-camel-mongodb-component-example.html

In my route, I convert it in JSON then use 'convertBodyTo(string.class) for mongo to recognize the file.

The code works well with regular route (sending the file to another folder for example). But when I run it for mongoDB, all I get in the console is my Process message again and again with my databased never being filled.As I don't receive any error message, I don't know how to find where the problem come from.

The mongoDB name, ip, users, password have been already checked multiple times.

I would be very grateful if someone could help me on this one. Here is the files I am using. (I will spare you the process file).

**camel-context.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
       http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring 
       http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd">
<bean id="myDb" class="com.mongodb.Mongo">
    <constructor-arg index="0">
        <bean class="com.mongodb.MongoURI">
            <constructor-arg index="0"
                value="mongodb://username:password@192.168.3.29:27017/db" />
        </bean>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>

<bean id="mongodb" class="org.apache.camel.component.mongodb.MongoDbComponent"></bean>

<camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <routeBuilder ref="camelRoute" />
</camelContext>

<bean id="camelRoute" class="infotel.camel.project01.CamelRoute" />
```

**Here is my RoutingFile:**

```
    @Component
    public class CamelRoute extends SpringRouteBuilder {

    final Processor myProcessor = new MyProcessor();
    final Processor myProcessorMongo = new MyProcessorMongo();

    final XmlJsonDataFormat xmlJsonFormat = new XmlJsonDataFormat();


    @Override
    public void configure() {
        xmlJsonFormat.setForceTopLevelObject(true);

        from("file:xml_files?noop=true").marshal(xmlJsonFormat).convertBodyTo(String.class).process(myProcessorMongo)
        .to("mongodb:myDb?database=test_bignav&collection=doc&operation=insert");

    }
}
```

**And finally here is my main:**

```
 public class MyMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
         ApplicationContext context = 
                    new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("META-INF/spring/camel-context.xml");

 }
}
```

Thanks a lot.

Edit:
Here is MyProcessorMongo edited to get the error:

public class MyProcessorMongo implements Processor{

```
public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("\n file transfered to mongo: "+ exchange.getIn().getHeader("CamelFileName"));
    exchange.getProperty(Exchange.EXCEPTION_CAUGHT, Exception.class).printStackTrace();
}
```

}

Comment: Please also share the code for MyProcessorMongo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dirty but quick, to get the error you can add this to you `configure()` method before your `from` :

```
.onException(Exception.class).handled(true).process(new Processor() {
    @Override
    public void process(Exchange exchange) {
        exchange.getProperty(Exchange.EXCEPTION_CAUGHT, Exception.class).printStackTrace();
    }
})
```

The `handled(true)` prevents your message from being processed again and again.

Answer (score 1):

Enable tracing with `trace="true"`:

```
<camelContext trace="true" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your help I have been able to get the error message.

The problem actually came from mongoDB itself and not camel or code. With the change on users the connection works and I'm able to insert document inside a collection.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the "**.process(myProcessorMongo)**" from route configuration .
 Input xml-> json conversion->string conversion -> Mongodb. 
 Above route will work.
 And you are passing the exchange object to myProcessorMongo but Out message is null so nothing will be inserted into MongoDB . Put exchange.getOut().getBody(); in the myProcessorMongo and print it.If its coming as null u have to get the input message from exchange Obj and set it back it in to Out message property in the exchange Object.